# SQL sum with overlapping date

Tags: sql, sum

I have a table that has following columns:

From
To
WorkQuota

Now I need the sum of the work quota that have an overlapping date. After execution of the sql query, I will check in my application if the sum is greater than 100.

Is it possible to do this in SQL?

Thanks in advance

shivan

EDIT:

I need to have the sum of the work quota from the records that overlap. But I think that's not possible like that in SQL.

Example:

Feb1-Feb3 80% - Feb2-Feb4 30% --> This should appear in my result as 110%, because it's overlapping and more than 100%.

Feb10-Feb12 50% - Feb14-Feb15 20% - Feb16-Feb18 100% - I don't care because dates are not overlapping

Feb20-Feb24 50% - Feb21-Feb22 20% - I don't care because the work quota is less than 100%

Comment: what exactly you want in output and please specify the database also that you are using.

Comment: I want to have the sum of the work quota for each overlapping date. Like that:

80
130
70
...

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: So I guess column "`From`" and column "`To`" are of type `Date`. Am I right ?

Comment: What is an overlapping date here? Do you mean that records Feb1-Feb3, Feb2-Feb6, and Feb4-Feb7 overlap and you want to see them as a group Feb1-Feb7 with the sum of their work quotas? You should always provide an example when asking such questions. We don't know your data. Simply show four or five records and the desired query result, so we know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query to get your output:

```
 SELECT t1.From ,t1.To, SUM(t1.WorkQuota) FROM TABLE t1 inner join TABLE t2 on t1.FROM = t2.TO GROUP BY t1.FROM,t1.To;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to do this in one step. So I wrote a funktion to check if dates are overlapping:

```
'Testing Function CheckDatesOverlap
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim dFrom1, dTo1, dFrom2, dTo2 As Date

    'Init Date
    dFrom2 = CDate("01.01.2000")
    dTo2 = CDate("01.01.2010")

    'There are 4 possibilities

    'Possibility 1:
    dFrom1 = CDate("01.01.1995")
    dTo1 = CDate("01.01.2005")

    If CheckDatesOverlap(dFrom1, dTo1, dFrom2, dTo2) Then
        MsgBox "Success"
    End If

    'Possibility 2:
    dFrom1 = CDate("01.01.2005")
    dTo1 = CDate("01.01.2015")

    If CheckDatesOverlap(dFrom1, dTo1, dFrom2, dTo2) Then
        MsgBox "Success"
    End If

    'Possibility 3:
    dFrom1 = CDate("01.01.2004")
    dTo1 = CDate("01.01.2008")

    If CheckDatesOverlap(dFrom1, dTo1, dFrom2, dTo2) Then
        MsgBox "Success"
    End If

    'Possibility 4:
    dFrom1 = CDate("01.01.1995")
    dTo1 = CDate("01.01.2015")

    If CheckDatesOverlap(dFrom1, dTo1, dFrom2, dTo2) Then
        MsgBox "Success"
    End If
End Sub

Public Function CheckDatesOverlap(ByVal dFrom1 As Date, ByVal dTo1 As Date, ByVal dFrom2 As Date, ByVal dTo2 As Date) As Boolean   
    If (dFrom1 >= dFrom2 And dFrom1 <= dTo2) Or (dTo1 >= dFrom2 And dTo1 <= dTo2) Or (dFrom1 < dFrom2 And dTo1 > dTo2) Then
        CheckDatesOverlap = True
    End If
End Function
```

I would really appreciate if sombody knows a solution in SQL for my problem. Otherwise I hope that my could might help somebody.